# MVC 4 - Create and Download .ZIP archive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zip

I'm using MVC4 and one of my views contains hyper links which allow to download a document from the view. In fact, I would also like to display a link which allows to download all the file compressed in a .zip archive. My files are stored in my database in a varbinary format.

My Download Action :

```
public ActionResult DownloadDocument(long id)
{
    Document element = db.Documents.Single(obj => obj.Id_Document == id);

    try
    {
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; Filename=\"" + element.Name + "\"");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "Binary");
        Response.BinaryWrite(element.Buffer);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return View("Details", element.ProductAllocationLog);

}
```

My view :

```
@model BuSIMaterial.Models.ProductAllocationLog
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ProductAllocationLog", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ProductAllocationLog</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Date :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "datepicker"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Message :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Allocation :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Id_ProductAllocation", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id_ProductAllocation)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Any idea about the way that I can use to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I tried the C# file compressor, read lots of tutorials about how to compress my files but any of them was adapted to my situation.

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565794/create-and-stream-image-archive-zip-file-for-download-c-sharp?rq=1